# Shouldn't the icon for "rejected" be green thumbs up?

Tags: feature-request

**TL;DR**

*Rejection of a patent is considered success for Ask Patents community, so shouldn't the icon for [rejected tag](https://patents.stackexchange.com/tags/rejected/info) be a greenish-thumbs-up instead of current reddish-thumbs-down ([image: reddish thumbs down rejected tag icon])?*

Rejection of a patent is considered a success ([...patents which have been **successfully** narrowed or rejected...](https://patents.stackexchange.com/tags/rejected/info)) and Ask Patents community is congratulated on successful rejection of a patent ([...Thanks to the YOU, the Ask Patents community...](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/scaling-based-on-pixel-density-microsoft-patent-application-prior-art-requ)).

As per Wikipedia article on "[Thumbs Signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumbs_signal)", thumbs-up often has a positive connotation (except in Germany, France, and Hungary), while thumbs-down often has a negative connotation. Similarly, in symbols, [green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green) is often used to represent "success", while [red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red) is usually reserved for "failure".

So while the current icon ([image: reddish thumbs down rejected tag icon]) may make sense from USPTO's perspective or from applicant's perspective, but from Ask Patents' user's perspective, I believe that the icon for [rejected tag](https://patents.stackexchange.com/tags/rejected/info) should be a greenish-thumbs-up instead of current reddish-thumbs-down.