# Should the "Rejected" banner be green color instead of red?

Tags: feature-request

We currently use this image to indicate that patents are rejected:

[image]

However, when visitors to the page view the site, it's highly likely that they would think "the challenge had been rejected", instead of "the patent had been rejected".

I believe this is detrimental to the growth of the site. If people are misled into thinking that most challenges are rejected, they may be discouraged from posting or aiding (submitting prior art) a challenge themselves.

Should we change the "Rejected" banner to be green color instead of red color?

<sub>Note this suggestion is highly linked to (but not a duplicate of) [another post by Vikrant](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/q/203/8289)</sub>.